# Adding an Image to a button inside a masklayer (CALayer)?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a button inside a CALayer and cannot find a way to add an image to it.

Here is my code. The button appears but....

```
        let button1 = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom) as UIButton
        button1.frame = CGRectMake(36, 100 , 36, 36)
        button1.addTarget(self, action: "Action:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

         // Create your mask layer

        let maskLayer: CALayer = CALayer()
        maskLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 150)
        maskLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
        maskLayer.addSublayer(button1.layer)
        maskLayer.contents = (UIImage(named: "RedDot.png")!.CGImage as! AnyObject)

        // Apply the mask to your uiview layer

        infoWindow.layer.addSublayer(maskLayer)



        return infoWindow
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to add button's layer as sublayer setting image to the button doesn't work. One way is to set layer content as below,

```
    button1.layer.contents = (UIImage(named: "image.png")!.CGImage as! AnyObject)
```

In this way you can't set other properties like pressed state etc.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: While this code looks good, I imagine masklayer needs to be involved. I ran the code and it produced " Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Comment: I think you have not updated image.png with proper one.